# Meaning of the El Universal hashtag "bajo reserva"

Tags: traducción

The Mexican newspaper El Universal runs several news items throughout the day across all its social media accounts. Of those, one particular practice that recently caught my attention is their use of this hashtag: **#BajoReserva**.

If I have noted correctly, they run at least one tweet with this hashtag every day. The piece with this hashtag also carries this tag on other platforms such as the El Universal app, its Facebook page, etc.

What could be the best way to interpret this expression in this context? I know the phrase literally translates as *under reservation* but in the context of news, it hardly makes any sense.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means *off the record*, but here it's just the name of a newspaper column; I don't know if the information in it is necessarily obtained *off the record*.

Comment: Ahhh...yes "off the record" makes sense. Is that like a well-known set phrase or something?

Comment: @TheLearner: Generically it means _in confidence_ or _confidentially_, and it's a known phrase. For the specific journalistic meaning, I think the English _“off the record”_ is used more. At least it is in Argentina.

Comment: I never have read ***bajo reserva*** as a synonymous with ***confidentially***